# How to estimate interpretable treatment effects using a marginal structural model?

Tags: panel-data, causality, propensity-scores, treatment-effect, marginal-effect

Say that I estimate a marginal structural model with weights obtained by inverse probability weighting. Imagine that my model looks something like: $Y_t = X_t + X_{t-1}$ again, with observations weighted by their inverse probability of receiving treatment and with $Y$ representing a discrete outcome.

Following the estimation of this model, I would like to meaningfully interpret the ATE. In a MSM, is the reported coefficient representative of the ATE? Or, are MSMs with discrete outcomes subject to the same concerns as other discrete outcome regression models ([Mood 2009](https://www.su.se/polopoly_fs/1.341161.1501927873!/menu/standard/file/Eur%20Sociol%20Rev-2010-Mood-67-82%20(1).pdf), [Daniel et al. 2020](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/bimj.201900297), [Norton et al. 2019](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jama/article-abstract/2728169), [Long and Mustillo 2018](https://jslsoc.sitehost.iu.edu/stata/groupsbrm/2018-07-13%20package/long-mustillo-groups-2018-07-13.pdf))? If so, does it make sense to use g-computation to estimate the ATE using a marginal structural model? I am unsure of this.

In the {marginaleffects} [user guide](https://marginaleffects.com/vignettes/ipw.html), there is a section on {marginaleffects} with IPW while using `avg_comparisons`, but I was wondering if this is still functional specifically within the context of a marginal structural model.